# Can I fix a point in Minkowski space to give it a vector space structure?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I looked up the term [Minkowski space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) on Wikipedia. It said

> *There is an alternative definition of Minkowski space as an affine space which views Minkowski space as a homogenous space of the Poincaré group with the Lorentz group as the stabilizer.*

In their book *Metric Affine Geometry*, Snapper and Troyer state on page 59:

It cannot be stressed enough that the affine space $X$ is not a vector space. Its points cannot be added and there is no way to multiply by scalars. No point in $X$ is preferred; they all play the same role. In particular, there is no point in $X$ which makes a better origin for a vector space than any other point.

The situation changes radically if we choose a point $c$ in $X$ and keep it fixed. It is now possible to make $X$ into a left vector space over $k$ by using the one-to-one mapping $f$ from $X$ onto $V$ defined by $f(x) = \overrightarrow{c,x}$ for each $x \in X$. All we do is carry the vector space structure of $V$ over to $X$ by means of the mapping $f$.

So here's my question: 
As I understand it, it makes sense to think of Minkowski space as an affine space since the basic principle of Special Relativity is that no point in $X$ is a preferred reference frame. But does that mean it is then impossible to "fix" a point in $X$ as  Snapper and Troyer say can be done? In other words, is there any physical meaning to the idea of fixing a point in the affine space or is that impossible according to SR?

Obviously I am trying to use a mathematician's idea to interpret what can be done physically with Minkowski space.

Comment: Is this the same idea by which one can define an "absolute" space in classical mechanics? If it is, then it probably runs into the same problem as in classical mechanics: there is no physical mechanism that can pick c! All such "fix points" are equally unphysical, even though nothing stops us from using them in all of our calculations. In the end all they are expressing by their equal meaninglessness is the very degeneracy that makes the theory "relative" to begin with. Having said all of this, there is a high likelihood that I am completely misunderstanding the idea.

Comment: I had similar thoughts, but I really have no idea so that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Does the text give any more context? How are the authors exploiting the vector space property of this construction?

Comment: Sure, let me see if I can provide some. On page 6-7, they say " the axiom system for $n$-dimensional affine space over a division ring $k$ consists of a nonempty set $X$, an $n$-dimensional left vector space $V$ over the division ring $k$, and an "action" of the additive group of $V$ on $X$. The elements of $X$ are called points and are denoted $x,y,z,...$; the elements of $V$ are called vectors and are denoted by $A,B,C,...$. Scalars are ways written on the left of vectors. The affine space defined by $X,V,k$ and the action of the additive group of $V$ on $X$ will be denoted by $(X,V,k)$.

Comment: (Continued) In case $k$ is the field of the real numbers $\Bbb{R}$, $(X,V,\Bbb{R})$ is called real affine space.

Comment: There should not be an physical meaning to picking a point. But you could think of it as an origin associated with a (very general!) class of observers. Of course, there is nothing to single out any particular inertial observer.

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like to me they are characterizing the structure that has no physical meaning, at least not in the standard interpretation.

Comment: Excellent. This was my impression and it seems to be the consensus on Physics SE as well.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Re *Is this the same idea by which one can define an "absolute" space in classical mechanics?* - Not at all. *There is no physical mechanism that can pick c!* Sure there is. Point at it! Point at any spot you want! We do this all the time: Arbitrarily pick some point as an origin, and voila! you can assign coordinates to any point in an affine space. How else are you going to assign coordinates to a point?

Comment: @DavidHammen I am confused. Is your comment in agreement with the conditions stated in Phoenix87's answer?

Comment: @StanShunpike - Absolutely. You used the phrase "preferred reference frame" to mean some frame that somehow stands out as unique (e.g., the aether frame that the Michelson–Morley experiment didn't find would have stood out as unique). There's another very different meaning of preferred frame, which is the frame in which one prefers to work. For example, the lab frame. Just because there is no preferred frame (first meaning) does not mean that there are no preferred frames (second meaning). That second meaning means one can use algebra instead of geometry.

Comment: @DavidHammen Oh, maybe I see your point. I remember reading in Wheeler and Taylor's book *Spacetime Physics*. They would always go between different frames. They had the Earth frame or the rocket frame or the lab frame. And obviously one could in this sense choose a preferred frame since all were defined in terms of the metric.  But there was no absolute frame. I think that's the distinction you are making if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: Exactly. Your statement in the question "*the basic principle of Special Relativity is that no point in X is a preferred reference frame*" seems to imply that you think there are no reference frames in SR. That's just wrong. A better way to look at the "no preferred frame" (first meaning) in SR is that all frames of reference are equally valid. You can use any frame you want.

Comment: @DavidHammen So just to clarify...based on what has been said in this thread, we can "fix a coordinate system on our affine space" (ie choose Earth, lab rocket frame etc) but it only behaves as a vector relative to the Lorentz group. For more general transformations (eg spacetime translations) we cannot fix a point because this would be like having an absolute frame of reference.

Comment: Sure you can. You're looking at it wrong. You pick this point as an origin, I pick that point as an origin, moving at some velocity *v* with respect to yours. We both assign coordinates to some third point in spacetime. What is the transformation from your representation of that point to mine (or from mine to yours)?

Comment: Related post by OP: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1083207/11127

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixing a point is more or less like fixing a coordinate system on your affine space. Then you can identify $X$ with $V$ as stated in the book, where the fixed point $c\in X$ is mapped to the origin of $V$. In other words, fixing a point $c$ in $X$ is like glueing a copy of $V$ onto $X$ in such a way that $O\in V$ overlaps with $c\in X$. As far as the Lorentz group is considered then the coordinates (i.e. the component of the glued copy of $V$ onto $X$) really behave like vectors, but this is no longer the case under more general transformations (consider for instance translations, or the action of the ray inversion from the conformal group).