# Why is the flat spacetime of special relativity not a linear vector space?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, vectors, linear-algebra

Why is the flat spacetime of special relativity, not a real linear vector space? It seems to satisfy all the axioms for a set to form a vector space. I mean adding to spacetime points $(t_1,\vec{r}_1)$ and $(t_2,\vec{r}_2)$, is yet another spacetime point $(t_1+t_2,\vec{r}_1+\vec{r}_2)$. So I don't see a problem with **closure**, or vector addition being **commutative** or **associative**. The **null vector** is the spacetime point $(0,\vec{0})$. I also hope that it is also closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Who says it's not? Also, what do you gain by giving it a vector space structure? How does it help?

Comment: It is a vector space since it is really just $\mathbb{R}^4$ endowed with the Lorentzian metric $\eta = \operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$, so you can of course define the operation of addition and multiplication by scalar as usual and gain a vector space structure. But being able to does not mean it is useful. What adding events would actually mean? In fact, when you view $\mathbb{R}^4$ with this Lorentzian product as a *spacetime* you are more interested in viewing $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a smooth manifold than as a vector space.

Comment: When you view $\mathbb{R}^4$ with this Lorentzian product as a space of four-vectors as four-momenta, or tangent vectors at some point in spacetime like four-velocities, then you are in a situation in which the vector space structure plays a role.

Comment: In this context, a “null vector” is a vector with zero norm using the metric. While the zero vector has 0 norm using the minkowski metric (and the Euclidean metric), there are non-zero null vectors in special relativity (unlike in Euclidean geometry).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158946/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 7):

Flat spacetime is more naturally described as an affine space, not a vector space. An affine space is basically a vector space without an origin. There is no unique natural event in flat spacetime which is naturally distinguished as "the" origin.

If we neglect curvature and take two events in spacetime say A is the supernova SN 2003fg and B is the supernova SN 2006gy then without choosing a third event and designating it as an origin, what event in spacetime is A+B?  Indeed, it doesn't make sense to add A and B, any more than it makes sense to add Paris to Caracas.

In contrast, without choosing an origin we can subtract B-A to get a vector. This is what an affine space does.

Comment: Related: [Torsors Made Easy](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html)

Comment: By "vector space without an origin", do you mean "a vector space without a null vector"? But why is there no natural null vector? When we talk about flat spacetime, isn't it the collection of events w.r.t a given inertial observer? Suppose the observer monitors a clock kept at rest in the origin of his or her coordinate system. When that clock reads t=5 s, can't we take that event as the "origin"? Please correct me.

Comment: @Solidification Yes, by origin I mean the unique vector $\vec 0$. The point is that the observer is something in addition to spacetime. Yes, you *can* use a given event on a given observer’s worldline as an origin, but the same is true of any other event on any other observer’s worldline. There is nothing about spacetime that distinguishes any of the infinite possible origins

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this to me. Let me paraphrase your point. Observers merely assign coordinate labels to events but events exist independently of the observers. Is that right? If so, I have a last question. When you say spacetime as a mathematical space, does each point must have to correspond to a physical event? In other words, is spacetime a collection of all possible spacetime locations or spacetime locations of real events (supernova explosion, turning on a light bulb, an apple falling from the tree etc)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you have it

Comment: @Solidification I think I may be reading your follow up a bit differently than Dale. If you're asking whether a physically noteworthy "thing" (like a supernova, or a firecracker exploding) has to happen in order for a point in spacetime to be called an event, the answer is *no*. Loosely speaking, an *event* is a point in space together with a time. If I consider the point three inches in front of my nose at precisely 3:17 PM tomorrow, that is called an *event* even if nothing physically interesting is occurring there.

Comment: @J.Murray Then adding two spacetime points A and B (component by component) gives me yet another spacetime point C and vector addition is closed even though A and B are physical events, C need not be. If that is so, it contradicts Dale's second paragraph, I think. I think, in that paragraph, Dale is trying to say that if A and B are physical events, then C also has to be a physical event but not just " point three inches in front of my nose at precisely 3:17 PM tomorrow".

Comment: @J.Murray I think Solidification is closer to my meaning than what you are saying. Saying 3 inches in front of my nose at 3:17 pm does identify an event, but it does so by adding an origin. That added origin is fine, but is an additional structure.  Any other origin could have been arbitrarily chosen without changing the physics. The choice of origin is conventional, not physical. That event exists even without choosing an origin, it just needs to be identified by what happens there. Hopefully not a supernova, but even some small thermal or quantum fluctuation is sufficient

Comment: @Dale I'm not referring to the presence or absence of an origin - As far as I can tell, Solidification is under the impression that an event must refer to something physical actually *happening* at some place and time. I am arguing that "event" is synonymous with "spacetime point," and no particular occurrence needs to be happening at that place and time. In my opinion, talking about thermal or quantum fluctuations is obfuscating the issue; treating GR purely classically, we can talk about points in spacetime even in the complete absence of matter or energy, so no fluctuations are needed.

Comment: @J.Murray yes, I agree that “event” is synonymous with “spacetime point”. I am not arguing against that. What I am trying to teach is that it is not necessary to arbitrarily choose an origin in order to *identify* an event. The mathematical structure that has that property is an affine space, not a vector space. Your description is problematic in that regard because it implied (in Solidification’s mind) the necessity of choosing an origin and forming a vector space

Comment: @Dale Fair enough. My concern was the with comment "When you say spacetime as a mathematical space, does each point must have to correspond to a physical event? [*No*] In other words, is spacetime a collection of all possible spacetime locations [*Yes, if 'location' includes time*] or spacetime locations of real events (supernova explosion, turning on a light bulb, an apple falling from the tree etc)? [*No*]" (my answers in brackets).

Comment: @J.Murray interesting. I think that you and I agree on the physics and the math, but not the translation into English. I would (and did) answer all three of those [Yes]. For me a "physical event" is still a physical event even if nothing interesting happens there, a physical event is just a point in spacetime. Physical events are certainly more difficult to *identify* if nothing interesting happens there, but they are no less physical events.

Comment: @Dale I fully agree with your assessment. My impression was that Solidification was using "physical event" to mean what you describe as something interesting happening, but perhaps I'm mistaken in that sense. Regardless, perhaps this back-and-forth will be helpful to clarify the issue (assuming it's not deleted first).